# Android extend EditText draw on canvas out of bounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

Im trying to draw text on `EditText` below by extending it and overriding `onDraw` function:

[image]

As you can see, the word gets cut off, from what am I seeing online, they don't do anything on the canvas aside from drawing on it. From what I've observed, I think because the canvas of the `EditText` is limited, that's why it is being cut off. **I know there's a better solution** rather than overriding `onDraw`, but I want to know the reason why this is happening. Can anybody explain or give a hint? Thank you very much.

**CustomEditText.java:**

```
public class CustomEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

private Rect mTitleRect;
private Rect mErrorTextRect;

private Paint mTitlePaint;
private Paint mErrorTextPaint;

private String mTitle = "";
private String mErrorText = "";

private int mEditTextHeight;

public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, R.attr.customEditTextStyle);
    init();
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init() {
    mTitleRect = new Rect();
    mErrorTextRect = new Rect();

    mTitlePaint = new Paint();
    mErrorTextPaint = new Paint();

    mTitlePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mTitlePaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_small));

    mErrorTextPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4336"));
    mErrorTextPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_small));
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText);

    try {
        mTitle = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_headerTitle);
        mErrorText = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_errorText);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mEditTextHeight = h;

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (mTitle != null && !mTitle.isEmpty()) {
        mTitlePaint.getTextBounds(mTitle, 0, mTitle.length(), mTitleRect);
        canvas.drawText(mTitle, getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop() - mTitleRect.height(), mTitlePaint);
    }

    if (mErrorText != null && !mErrorText.isEmpty()) {
        mErrorTextPaint.getTextBounds(mErrorText, 0, mErrorText.length(), mErrorTextRect);
        canvas.drawText(mErrorText, getPaddingLeft(), mEditTextHeight + mErrorTextRect.height() / 2, mErrorTextPaint);
    }
}
}
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomEditText">
    <attr name="errorText" format="string|reference" />
    <attr name="headerTitle" format="string|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**XML:**

```
<com.mypackage.CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"
                app:errorText="errorrrr"
                app:headerTitle="testing title" />
```

Comment: try to add android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false" to this EditText and ALL its parent layouts

Comment: Please edit question and  add 'R.styleable.CustomEditText'  xml.

Comment: Updated :) Will try the clip, thank you

Comment: Hi @Subzero, thank you it is now being displayed :) but it seems that it doesn't work from what I expected, it is not counted as view on `EditText` because it is not being wrap inside, instead it just goes outside and the below views (the password) doesn't adjust. It just overlaps :/

Comment: And by the way, the title also (which is on top) is cut off :( I've updated the image by the way

Comment: Theory: I think the answer for this is to redraw the whole canvas on another canvas with space for the text, instead of drawing on the existing canvas in which the whole edit text is in. You cannot move it, as it represents the current canvas, you need to put it in another canvas to move it as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misinterpreting android canvas coordinate. Origin coordinate (0, 0) of a canvas is at the very left top x-coordinate is increasing as you go to the right and y-coordinate is increasing as you go to the bottom.
[image]
You need to pass left top coordinate of the text that you want to draw.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)

I could not understand where do you want to draw the the text so assuming that you want to draw at the top left of the view have to call draw text like this

```
canvas.drawText(mTitle, getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), mTitlePaint);
```

Comment: thanks for this, I will try this out once I encountered the problem again. As of now, I just created a custom view with TextView and EditText as 1 layout, then I just created a method to return the EditText incase I need to modify something on the EditText itself.

Comment: You are welcome, I think it is also  a better solution than overriding onDraw of the EditText

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

private Rect mTitleRect;
private Rect mErrorTextRect;

private Paint mTitlePaint;
private Paint mErrorTextPaint;

private String mTitle = "";
private String mErrorText = "";

private int mEditTextHeight;

public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
    init(attrs);
}

private void init() {
    mTitleRect = new Rect();
    mErrorTextRect = new Rect();

    mTitlePaint = new Paint();
    mErrorTextPaint = new Paint();

    mTitlePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mTitlePaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_small));

    mErrorTextPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4336"));
    mErrorTextPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_small));
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText);

    try {
        mTitle = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_headerTitle);
        mErrorText = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_errorText);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mEditTextHeight = h;

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    setPadding(0, 0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_small));

    if (mTitle != null && !mTitle.isEmpty()) {
        mTitlePaint.getTextBounds(mTitle, 0, mTitle.length(), mTitleRect);
        canvas.drawText(mTitle, getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop() - mTitleRect.height(), mTitlePaint);
    }

    if (mErrorText != null && !mErrorText.isEmpty()) {
        mErrorTextPaint.getTextBounds(mErrorText, 0, mErrorText.length(), mErrorTextRect);
        canvas.drawText(mErrorText, getPaddingLeft(), getHeight(), mErrorTextPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried adding padding programmatically but it just pushes the hint :(

Comment: last line canvas.drawText(mErrorText, getPaddingLeft(), getHeight(), mErrorTextPaint);

Comment: That's the first thing I've tried actually, it shows below but the top is also a problem. It is just more likely a patch, not a proper fix for the solution Im looking. Thank you by the way for the suggestion :)

Comment: It's best to draw inside the view. For this use padding. If you want to draw outside the  view, then you need to set android:clipChildren="false" and android:clipToPadding="false" in root layout. But watch that other views are not overlapped your picture.